# Toggle class name in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to stripe a table based on the time in each row. For example:

```
Blah -  time 1
Blah2 - time 1
Blah3 - time 2
Blah4 - time 3
Blah5 - time 4
```

I need time 1 to be one colour (blue for example) time 2 to be colour black, time 3 to toggle back blue. I am trying to toggle the colour changed based on when the time has changed. My PHP so far:

```
    while($main_Row = $main_Results->fetch_assoc()){
        if( $pickup_Time == $main_Row['pickup_Time'] ){
            $stripe = "blue";   
        }
        else{
            $stripe = "black";  
            $pickup_Time = $main_Row['pickup_Time'];
        }

        echo '<tr class="'.$stripe.'">';
        echo '<td>Blah'.$i.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$main_Row['pickup_Time'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

What I have currently is not giving me the results I desire. I feel I'm missing something, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when the time has changed to what?

Comment: @syedmohamed when it changes to a different time, in my example, when it changes from time 1 to time 2.

Comment: @Mate yeah no soon as I posted this question I picked up on that >.> I have since changed that but still getting not getting what I want

Comment: Where is your css classes 'blue' and 'black'? If you don't have them, you should use: `echo '<tr style="color: '.$stripe.'">';`

Comment: @gurkov CSS is in another stylesheet. That has been tested and is working already :) I just need to apply the classes correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pickup_Time = "";
$stripe = "";
while($main_Row = $main_Results->fetch_assoc()){
    if( $pickup_Time != $main_Row['pickup_Time'] ){
        $stripe = $stripe == "blue" ? "black" : "blue";   
    }

    echo '<tr class="'.$stripe.'">';
    echo '<td>Blah'.$i.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$main_Row['pickup_Time'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $pickup_Time = $main_Row['pickup_Time'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly threw something together, it's a little verbose, but I wanted to make the general intent and process clear.

This will stripe per row, to stripe per column you would add your classes onto the td. If you want to change how many stripes before it cycles over again, change the modulo to whatever number you want.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>

        <style>
            .red {
                background-color: red;
            }

            .blue {
                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $mysqli = new mysqli('', '', '', '');

        $qry = "SELECT * FROM data";
        $result = $mysqli->query($qry);

        $counter = 1;

        echo "<table>";
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

            $class = "";
            if( $counter % 3 == 1 ) {
                $class = "blue";
            } else if ( $counter % 3 === 2 ) {
                $class = "red";
            }

            echo '<tr class="' . $class . '">';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

            $counter += 1;
        }
        echo "</table>";

        $result->free();

        $mysqli->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a nice, generic answer which could apply to anyone who stumbles across this question. Kudos mate :)